# GetScreenshot with ChromeDriver misses last action

Tags: selenium, screenshot, selenium-chromedriver

I've created a Selenium test where I click on a form and take a screenshot afterwards and when I run my test it works fine with IE and the Firefox Drivers but with Chrome it looks like the screenshot is too fast taken.

Here's my code:

```
  IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.klein.nl/contact/");
  driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

  var sendButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@title='Bevestig']"));
  sendButton.Click();

  var screenshotFF = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
  driver.Quit();

  driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\Selenium Drivers", new InternetExplorerOptions() { IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true });
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.klein.nl/contact/");
  driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
  sendButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@title='Bevestig']"));
  sendButton.Click();

  var screenshotIE = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
  driver.Quit();

  driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Selenium Drivers");
  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.klein.nl/contact/");
  driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
  //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));

  sendButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@title='Bevestig']"));
  sendButton.Click();

  var screenshotChrome = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
  driver.Quit();
```

When I view the screenshots the last one will not show the input textboxes with a red border. 
How can I prevent that the screenshot is taken too soon?

Answer (score 0):

do some synchronisation after sendButton.Click(); For example wait for mentioned input textboxes.

Comment: I've tried that and its still to fast with the screenshot. For example I've changed the click action with a SendKeys in the first textbox where I enter the word Chrome and then take a screenshot. Now only the letter C is shown on my screenshot.

Comment: this is not what I mentioned. use WebDriverWait + ExpectedCondtions.visibilityOf(yourTextBox)